# "example table" shows pending in jbehave

Tags: parameters, jbehave

Story file

```
When the user enters the required values as: <dataTable> in the text box

|sno|name|city_name|state_name|country_name|
|1|Bank of America|Chicago|         |            |
|2|JP Morgan      |       |Illinois |            |
```

Steps.class

```
@When("the user enters the required values as: <dataTable> in the text box")
public void enterDetails(@Named("dataTable") ExamplesTable dataTable){
```

in the output I see

```
When the user enters the required values as: <dataTable> in the text box (PENDING)
```

The test was passed but the step shows as Pending.

I've tried with below $ parameter as well.

Story file

```
When the user enters the required values as: $dataTable in the text box
```

Steps.class

```
    @When("the user enters the required values as: $dataTable in the text box")
public void enterDetails(ExamplesTable dataTable){
```

This time, the test was failed in the below step.

```
When the user enters the required values as: $dataTable in the text box (FAILED)
(org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path '$dataTable' not found by class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2)
```

Can any one guide me over here. Do I need to update any configuration in my Storyrunner file? If so, please shed some light over here. I've checked on JBehave tutorial, but couldnt get much info on this
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html

Please note I use Jbehave with Gherkin

Current storyrunner file which extends JunitStories

```
**    @Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();

    return new SeleniumConfiguration()
            .useSeleniumContext(context)
            .useWebDriverProvider(driverProvider)
            .useStepMonitor(new SeleniumStepMonitor(contextView, context, new SilentStepMonitor()))
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass))
            .useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters().addConverters(new ParameterConverters.DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                    .withFormats(Format.STATS,
                            Format.CONSOLE,
                            Format.HTML
                    )
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withFailureTrace(true));
}**
```

Comment: JBehave's on-line documentation is not very clear on the use of ExamplesTable at all to me.  I would instead tokenize each entry.  I know it makes for a longer When line, but it works, and it might be clearer for others to see what's going on.  I think you understand where I'm going on this but I'd be glad to show an example as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the comment. Do you mean any of the below two or a new way?   
When the user enters  <sno> in the text box   
When the user enters <name> in the text box   
When the user enters  <city_name> in the text box   
When the user enters <state_name> in the text box  
When the user enters  <country_name> in the text box  
|sno|name|city_name|state_name|country_name|  
|1|Bank of America|Chicago|||  
or  
When the user enters the required values as <dataTable> in the text box  
|dataTable|  
|1,Bank of America,Chicago,,|

Comment: You could break it down into multiple steps like that, but I meant more like `When the user enters <sno>, <name>, <city_name>, <state_name>,  and <country_name>` and then name each parameter using Named in the steps definition.  I'm a bit pedantic, though, so to make it look nice on reports (JBehave or Extent, etc.) I'd really use something like `When the users enters name '<name>', ... so that the parameters, especially if there are missing ones, are clear on the report.

Comment: Thanks @BillHileman for your comments. I'd around 24 columns, so checking something similar to that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step syntax in the story file:

```
When the user enters the required values as:
|sno|name           |city_name|state_name|country_name|
|1  |Bank of America|Chicago  |          |            |
in the text box
```

Step implementation:

```java
@When("the user enters the required values as:$dataTablein the text box")
public void enterDetails(@Named("dataTable") ExamplesTable dataTable) {
    // Put step implementation here
}
```

More details are in the official documentation:
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html

Comment: This is what I'm checking for. Thanks @VaL. I could able to read the data now from the table. But for the below scenario, instead of going through each table row to look up button, the system enters, replaces the values with the next one, so I could only see the last row result instead of all the rows.   
        When the user enters the required values: 
    |sno|name |city_name|state_name|country_name| 
    |1 |Bank of America|Chicago |          | | 
    |2 |JP Morgan      |        | Illinois | | 
    And the user clicks on the look up button

Updated the question as well